# If a feed follows another feed, will it also see the feeds it follows?

Tags: getstream-io

Suppose I have 3 feeds:

```
a: contains an activity
b: follows a
c: follows b
```

I've set this up and it appears that while feed b will see the activity in feed a, feed c does not. Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. That is the expected behavior.

When B wants to share something that was posted in Feed A, then you can add some kind of activity to feed B with a verb (for example) "share", or "retweet", with the same foreign ID as the activity posted in feed A.